# Xcode simulator table view is black

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios-simulator

When running my Xcode project in the simulator, my `UITableView` in my `UIViewController` (not `UITableViewController`) is black.

Here is an image of my simulator:

[image]

Code for my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyPinpointsTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.titleLabel.text = myPinpoints[indexPath.row].title
    cell.locationLabel.text = myPinpoints[indexPath.row].location
    cell.dateLabel.text = myPinpoints[indexPath.row].date
    cell.pinpointImage.image = UIImage(data: myPinpoints[indexPath.row].image) 

    return cell
}
```

Here are the folders that I have:

[image]

`Main.storyboard`:

[image]

The error message I get when I add `print(myPinpoints)` to `numberOfRowsInSection`

> [ (entity: Details; id: 0xd000000000080000  ; data: )]
>   [ (entity: Details; id: 0xd000000000080000  ; data: )]
>   [ (entity: Details; id: 0xd000000000080000  ; data: )]
>   [ (entity: Details; id: 0xd000000000080000  ; data: )]
>   [ (entity: Details; id: 0xd000000000080000  ; data: )]
>   [ (entity: Details; id: 0xd000000000080000  ; data: )]
>   [ (entity: Details; id: 0xd000000000080000  ; data: )]
>   [ (entity: Details; id: 0xd000000000080000  ; data: )]
>   [ (entity: Details; id: 0xd000000000080000  ; data: )]
>   [ (entity: Details; id: 0xd000000000080000  ; data: )]
>   [ (entity: Details; id: 0xd000000000080000  ; data: )]

Comment: Do use the data source?

Comment: @MarcoSantarossa I am using the Core Data data source

Comment: Put log in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and confirm if your `delegate` and `dataSoruce` in your tableview is working

Comment: @pedrouan Okay. Thanks for the heads up. I see this now. Is there any way that you can suggest we can solve this?

Comment: @jose920405 I have added my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. The `delegate` and `dataSource` are connected.

Comment: if you change the `background color` in `tableview`, the change is applied?

Comment: Check your tableView background color. Also set break points or Print("dummies") inide your table view functions will give an idea !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may miss some stuff:

**1)** Check whether your tableView has set the class named as that on in your code. You find the input field to type the name of the class in Attributes inspector of the tableView.
[image]

**2)** Check whether you implemented methods, that comform to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource Protocol.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // I see you only have 1 section now
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//you should return appropriate number
   return 3
}
```

**3)** Check whether your table is properly connected from Storyboard to your UIViewController =>

As your tableView is inside UIViewController, check whether you set delegate and datasource for tableView in your controller (CTRL drag from table to FileOwner - rounded yellow icon in storyboard scene frame.)

[image]

**4)** Make sure, you set **protocols** that your UIViewController should conform to - i.e. delegate and dataSource protocols:

```
class MyPinpointsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource { ...
```

**5) Check your datasource**, as it may not be returning any items in `cellForRow()` method. It can by simply tested in `print(dataSource)` in any of TableView's delegate methods.

**6) Check possible autolayout issues**, as the important subviews could be out of visible part of the view.

Comment: I don't understand the top step. The other two are implemented. My UITableView is an IBOutlet that is connected.

Comment: I added an image to show what folders I have, so that might help, as I don't have as many as I usually would.

Comment: I'm not having trouble with any steps. They're just not working.

Comment: Also, with the first step, my `tableView` has an `IBOutlet`, but not a custom class.

Comment: Yes, I did follow a tutorial, but I followed the steps and checked them.

Comment: I've added it now.

Comment: I added the error message to the question that I get when I add print(myPinpoints)

Comment: When I added `print(dataSource)` to my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I get an error saying (not printed in the console, but a normal red warning) that it does not recognise the identifier 'dataSource'.

Comment: When I put `return 1`, the simulator is still black.

Comment: Yes, they're set as dynamic prototype.

Comment: Could you suggest anything I could check/show you with my Core Data?

Comment: It's definitely not about them. Your tableView does not show any table. Try to remove constraints of that table, to make sure whether your table View is visible on the screen. The last possible option is to post the full project, if it is secure for you.

Comment: Removing the contraints made the `tableView` appear, but my elements in it are now off.

Comment: @AnnabelleSykes This question 'simulator table view is black' should be marked as solved, so please make appropriate action to this question (vote, accept) what you are fine with, and ask another question, as your issues are related to autolayout.

Comment: Totally agree. Thanks for all the help.