# Why the tableview does not show up while the title bar does show up in ios simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios-simulator

I added a segue onto "Tag Location Button" to a new Table View named "Tag Location" which is embedded in a Navigation Controller. However, when I run it in the iOS Simulator, it only shows the top title bar with 'cancel' and 'done' button but without the tableview content below.

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y13xm.jpg)

Comment: is that table view content static?

Comment: have you set datasource and delegate methods?

Comment: Check these points first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39300137/661022

Comment: As per your screenshot, seems like your tableView's cells are static. If not make sure they are static or they are dynamic please confirm delegate and datasource.

Comment: I drug a normal table view controller from object library without any extra settings. It has delegate methods and datasource, the problem is I think it should have empty table view cells whether there is datasource or not. But now it does not show up. BTW, the first "Tag Location" should be "Tag Location Button". Thanks for your comments.

Comment: And my tableView's cells are static.

Comment: This looks more like the view is manipulated at runtime: either the tableView subview has been removed (e.g. `tableView.removeFromSuperview()`) or it's been hidden (e.g. `tableView.hidden = true`, `tableView.alpha = 0.0`) or you've checked one of those settings in Xcode's Attributes Inspector ("remove at runtime" or "hidden" or "Alpha" has been set to 0.0). Did you check all those possibilities?

Comment: Or another opaque view has been laid out on top of it (least likely but technically possible). Or the constraints have been manipulated during runtime to result in a zero size or off-screen location. For all of the possibilities I raised here & in previous comment show us your runtime debug output. For layout issues show the `frame` property of the `tableView`.

Comment: Thank you guys very much, I made some comparison with other project and  find the problem is that I didn't delete the preset: "- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {}" and
"- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {}" . If I delete them and run again, everything goes ok for now. But I still didn't know the reason, I will dig it and will be appreciate if you guys can share any point about this problem.